Must reload sendmail for gmail relay
I have just upgraded versuion for Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS using  update-manager. In seventeen years, this is the very first time I have upgraded versions without a fresh install and it went `surprisingly well, with one exception: I have to invoke
sudo`/etc/init.d/sendmail reload

before I can send an email to myself from the command line. Otherwise I get a
stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]

In /var/log/mail.log.
My system has been configured as per the instructions at https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay. In the previous version it worked flawlessly. By inspecting /etc/mail and /etc/mail/auth-info it appears that hash map for /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth seems to have been done properly and that 'remake' of /etc/mail/sendmai.mc seems to have been done properly by the installation.
Still, if I invoke something like
echo "Just testing my sendmail gmail relay" | mail -s "Sendmail gmail Relay" me@gmail.com

I get the aforementioned error and no email is received until I do a reload of sendmail (see code above).
I would like to correct this issue so that I don't have to keep reloading sendmail. Any and all ideas are welcome.

FYI: I tend to be most familiar with simple window managers like fluxbox, and I am most comfortable addressing system issues from the command line.

Shouldn't everything be using systemd rather than traditional SysV services these days? Is the sendmail service enabled (systemctl status sendmail.service)?

That is a whole nother issue. I am getting errors using systemctl. This window is limiting input so to be brief I get this error and more : MTA is already running.

You can [edit] your question to include any additional information

Thank you for that steeldriver. Good tip.
